# How to set privacy policy url for a fb app when working on localhost?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, localhost

I am working on a local application that needs to retrieve data from user's Facebook profile. As long as I can see, by default I can only get name, picture and age range, but I need many others information like education, location, likes and so on. I tried to submit approval for these items, but Facebook won't set my submission because I don't have a Privacy Policy URL added. I don't know what Privacy Policy URL to add because I'm working on localhost.

Please help me figure it out and excuse me if my question is wrong, it's the first time when I work with fb api. Also, if there is another way to retrieve this items, I would be more than happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

It's saying that

> in order to help you craft your Facebook Login experience, your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.

and

> Also, if you're the developer of an app and are the only person using it, then your app doesn't need to go through review. Since you're the developer, all app capabilities should be available. You will still need to take your app out of developer mode, but you should be able to do that without going through review.

So, to be able to develop your app and request extended permissions, you don't need to pass your app to review, as long as you test with an app admin/developer/tester.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I read more carefully the documentation, this question seems so meaningless.